# Filtering data from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.DataFrame({'vehicle':['car','car','car','car','car','car','bus','bus','bus','bus','bus','bus','car','car','car','car','car','car','bus','bus','bus','bus','bus','bus'],
'expecteddate':['2/24/2022','2/24/2022','3/15/2022','3/15/2022','4/20/2022','4/20/2022','2/24/2022','2/24/2022','3/15/2022','3/15/2022','4/20/2022','4/20/2022','2/24/2022','2/24/2022','3/15/2022','3/15/2022','4/20/2022','4/20/2022','2/24/2022','2/24/2022','3/15/2022','3/15/2022','4/20/2022','4/20/2022'],'range':[240,240,240,240,240,240,300,300,300,300,300,300,240,240,240,240,240,240,300,300,300,300,300,300],'color':['blue','red','blue','red','blue','red','blue','red','blue','red','blue','red','blue','red','blue','red','blue','red','blue','red','blue','red','blue','red'],'discount':[70,80,90,60,40,50,120,110,130,140,80,90,60,40,50,30,70,45,130,100,140,120,80,90],'price1':[60,40,90,50,40,50,100,100,130,140,80,90,50,40,90,60,40,50,30,40,130,70,70,40],'date':['2/18/2022','2/18/2022','2/18/2022','2/18/2022','2/18/2022','2/18/2022','2/18/2022','2/18/2022','2/18/2022','2/18/2022','2/18/2022','2/18/2022','2/17/2022','2/17/2022','2/17/2022','2/17/2022','2/17/2022','2/17/2022','2/17/2022','2/17/2022','2/17/2022','2/17/2022','2/17/2022','2/17/2022']})
print(data)
```

My dataframe looks like

```
vehicle expecteddate  range color  discount  price1       date
0      car    2/24/2022    240  blue        70      60  2/18/2022
1      car    2/24/2022    240   red        80      40  2/18/2022
2      car    3/15/2022    240  blue        90      90  2/18/2022
3      car    3/15/2022    240   red        60      50  2/18/2022
4      car    4/20/2022    240  blue        40      40  2/18/2022
5      car    4/20/2022    240   red        50      50  2/18/2022
6      bus    2/24/2022    300  blue       120     100  2/18/2022
7      bus    2/24/2022    300   red       110     100  2/18/2022
8      bus    3/15/2022    300  blue       130     130  2/18/2022
9      bus    3/15/2022    300   red       140     140  2/18/2022
10     bus    4/20/2022    300  blue        80      80  2/18/2022
11     bus    4/20/2022    300   red        90      90  2/18/2022
12     car    2/24/2022    240  blue        60      50  2/17/2022
13     car    2/24/2022    240   red        40      40  2/17/2022
14     car    3/15/2022    240  blue        50      90  2/17/2022
15     car    3/15/2022    240   red        30      60  2/17/2022
16     car    4/20/2022    240  blue        70      40  2/17/2022
17     car    4/20/2022    240   red        45      50  2/17/2022
18     bus    2/24/2022    300  blue       130      30  2/17/2022
19     bus    2/24/2022    300   red       100      40  2/17/2022
20     bus    3/15/2022    300  blue       140     130  2/17/2022
21     bus    3/15/2022    300   red       120      70  2/17/2022
22     bus    4/20/2022    300  blue        80      70  2/17/2022
23     bus    4/20/2022    300   red        90      40  2/17/2022
```

from this dataframe we have two vehicles ,three expecteddates ,range,two colors ,discount and date.
We have filter rows based on condition like, if latest date discount=latest date price1 and latest date price1=previous date price1, if condition matches print such rows regarding latest date

this should filtered based on vehicle,expecteddate,range,color and date

Output looks like

```
    Vehicle     expecteddate    range    color    discount  price1    date
Car              3/15/2022      240         blue      90     90  2/18/2022
Car              3/15/2022      240        blue       40     40   2/18/2022
Car              4/20/2022       240        red       50     50   2/18/2022
Bus              3/15/2022       300        blue      130   130  2/18/2022
```

vehicles are not limited to two like car and bus ,it has many vehicles and data is not always have equal rows in vehicle and range columns and date is not limited to two dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we threat our date columns as such:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

Then, we can iterate each group (notice we do not group by date, because we need them for our conditions):

```
output_rows = list()  # We'll store here the relevant rows

for _, group_df in df.groupby(["vehicle", "expecteddate", "range", "color"]):
    # For each group, we find the row of the latest dates using `.nlargest(2)`
    group_df = group_df.nlargest(2, "date")[["discount", "price1"]]

    # Now we can check both conditions and retrieve a boolean (True or False)
    condition_1 = (group_df.iloc[0, 0] == group_df.iloc[0, 1])
    condition_2 = (group_df.iloc[0, 1] == group_df.iloc[-1, 1])

    # If both conditions are True, we store the date in our output list
    if condition_1 and condition_2:
        output_rows.append(group_df.index[0])

# Finally, we create a dataframe with the relevant rows
output_df = df.loc[output_rows]
```

This is the output I got for your sample date:

```
  vehicle expecteddate  range color  discount  price1       date
8     bus   2022-03-15    300  blue       130     130 2022-02-18
2     car   2022-03-15    240  blue        90      90 2022-02-18
4     car   2022-04-20    240  blue        40      40 2022-02-18
5     car   2022-04-20    240   red        50      50 2022-02-18
```

Comment: thanks answer accepted ,is there any way to speed up output without looping. As my dataset is large

Comment: @KrishnaPrasad I just edited my answer with some changes. I simplified the operations and store a smaller value. Ley me know if there's a speed up.

Comment: name error  latest_date_row  at. Append()

Comment: Is that the code of the previous solution? Did you try the current version?

Comment: Yes getting name error, when i try current version. Previous version is working fine

Comment: Is everything same as previous code, do I need to change only condition line in code ?

Comment: @KrishnaPrasad my bad, forgot to update the content of the `if` block and the `output_df` creation, but now they're updated

Comment: It is showing blank screen taking time to display result, for my large dataset. Can we do by merging today's date data to previous date data in single dataframe and filtering data based on our condition. If possible can u implement, I am unable to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can filter like this:

```
data.loc[data['discount']==data['price1']]
```

Comment: Pls check condition once. It will not give desired output